# Python. Convert string to dictionary containing numpy arrays

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy

I have a string which has this structure:

```
{0: [array([5.1, 3.5, 1.4, 0.2]), array([4.9, 3. , 1.4, 0.2]), 1: [array([7. , 3.2, 4.7, 1.4]), array([6.4, 3.2, 4.5, 1.5]), 2: [array([6.3, 3.3, 6. , 2.5]), array([7.1, 3. , 5.9, 2.1])]}
```

It is in the form of a python dictionary containing numpy arrays.
How can I turn this string into a python dictionary containing numpy arrays?

Thanks for the replies already. I can't simply just change the string because the string is an output of a python file that I want to pipe to another one. I could go and change the format of this output, but I was rather hoping to avoid that.

Comment: So, let me guess, you dumped some string representation of your dictionary to a text-file, and now you need to deserialize it? The solution is *not to use this format in the first place*. You should have used something like `pickle`

Comment: I'd copy-n-paste the string to an interactive python session (eg. `ipython`), edit it by changing the `array` to `np.array` and then executing it.  Alternatively, copy to file, make that change, and import it.  Though when I do that, it doesn't run - must be some mismatch of brackets.

Comment: Thanks for the replies. I've edited the information in the question to address your comments.

Answer (score 0):

In an interactive `ipython` session is created an alias:
In [7]: array = np.array

and edited a copy-n-paste of your sample.  I had to add a couple of closing `]`:

```
In [8]: data = {0: [array([5.1, 3.5, 1.4, 0.2]), array([4.9, 3. , 1.4, 0.2])], 1
   ...: : [array([7. , 3.2, 4.7, 1.4]), array([6.4, 3.2, 4.5, 1.5])], 2: [array(
   ...: [6.3, 3.3, 6. , 2.5]), array([7.1, 3. , 5.9, 2.1])]}
```

Now a simple execute works:

```
In [9]: data
Out[9]: 
{0: [array([5.1, 3.5, 1.4, 0.2]), array([4.9, 3. , 1.4, 0.2])],
 1: [array([7. , 3.2, 4.7, 1.4]), array([6.4, 3.2, 4.5, 1.5])],
 2: [array([6.3, 3.3, 6. , 2.5]), array([7.1, 3. , 5.9, 2.1])]}
```

or with a string (corrected):

```
In [10]: astr="{0: [array([5.1, 3.5, 1.4, 0.2]), array([4.9, 3. , 1.4, 0.2])], 1
    ...: : [array([7. , 3.2, 4.7, 1.4]), array([6.4, 3.2, 4.5, 1.5])], 2: [array
    ...: ([6.3, 3.3, 6. , 2.5]), array([7.1, 3. , 5.9, 2.1])]}"
In [11]: astr
Out[11]: '{0: [array([5.1, 3.5, 1.4, 0.2]), array([4.9, 3. , 1.4, 0.2])], 1: [array([7. , 3.2, 4.7, 1.4]), array([6.4, 3.2, 4.5, 1.5])], 2: [array([6.3, 3.3, 6. , 2.5]), array([7.1, 3. , 5.9, 2.1])]}'
```

I can do an `exec` or `eval`:

```
In [15]: eval(astr)
Out[15]: 
{0: [array([5.1, 3.5, 1.4, 0.2]), array([4.9, 3. , 1.4, 0.2])],
 1: [array([7. , 3.2, 4.7, 1.4]), array([6.4, 3.2, 4.5, 1.5])],
 2: [array([6.3, 3.3, 6. , 2.5]), array([7.1, 3. , 5.9, 2.1])]}
```

Use of `eval` is often discouraged because it can be hacked.  But the safer `ast_eval` only works with dict, list and tuples, not `np.array`.  One way or other you have to edit the string so it is a valid Python/numpy expression.

Answer (score 0):

I changed how the string was being being produced so that it was in the form of a dictionary containing python lists instead of numpy arrays.
With this I could just use `ast.literal_eval()` to deseriealize it.